# Dynamically add double click event to new sheet. VBA

Tags: excel, vba, events, dynamic

VBA. I have figured out how to add an event that triggers on a changed cell, but for some reson am unable to do it for a clicked cell. Eventually I'd like events to trigger on when a user double clicks inside column A. This is as far as I can get.

```
Sub CreateEventProcedure() 
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject 
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent 
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule 
    Dim LineNum As Long 
    Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character  

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject 
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook") 
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule 
    
    With CodeMod 
        LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Open", "Workbook") 
        LineNum = LineNum + 1 
        .InsertLines LineNum, "    MsgBox " & DQUOTE & "Hello World" & DQUOTE 
    End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub CreateEventDBlClickProcedure()
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject, VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule, LineNum As Long

    Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook")
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
    'Check if the event is not already created:
    If CodeMod.Find("Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick", 1, 1, CodeMod.CountOfLines, 1, False) = True Then
            MsgBox "Event already created...": Exit Sub
    End If

    With CodeMod
        .AddFromString "Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)" & vbCrLf & _
                       "    MsgBox  ""Hello World from sheet "" & Sh.Name" & vbCrLf & _
                       "End Sub"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Hailey Bradshaw: Did you find time to test the code? Didn't the above code solve your problem?